# Problem javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException

Tags: java, database, jpa, exception

I'm creating a role with my form and this is the first time I've had this error, and I've been at it for 20 days.

Apparently, the problem is with my save and/or my "roles" entity.
How can I solve this problem?
Here are the files:
My error :

```
20-Oct-2021 05:07:51.658 AVERTISSEMENT [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute #{rolesBean.newRoles}: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Entity no longer exists in the database: entities.Roles@780b0a91.
    javax.faces.FacesException: #{rolesBean.newRoles}: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Entity no longer exists in the database: entities.Roles@780b0a91.
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.getNavigationOutcome(ActionListenerImpl.java:96)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:71)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:222)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:847)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:1012)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:55)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:450)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
        at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
        at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Entity no longer exists in the database: entities.Roles@780b0a91.
        at com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:76)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.getNavigationOutcome(ActionListenerImpl.java:82)
        ... 49 more
    Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Entity no longer exists in the database: entities.Roles@780b0a91.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.refresh(EntityManagerImpl.java:1160)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.refresh(EntityManagerImpl.java:1042)
        at services.Service.refreshEntity(Service.java:55)
        at managedBean.RolesBean.save(RolesBean.java:257)
        at managedBean.RolesBean.newRoles(RolesBean.java:166)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
        at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
        at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:65)
        at com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:66)
        ... 50 more
20-Oct-2021 05:07:51.661 GRAVE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Entity no longer exists in the database: entities.Roles@780b0a91.
    at com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.getNavigationOutcome(ActionListenerImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:222)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:847)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:1012)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:55)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:450)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Entity no longer exists in the database: entities.Roles@780b0a91.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.refresh(EntityManagerImpl.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.refresh(EntityManagerImpl.java:1042)
    at services.Service.refreshEntity(Service.java:55)
    at managedBean.RolesBean.save(RolesBean.java:257)
    at managedBean.RolesBean.newRoles(RolesBean.java:166)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:65)
    at com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:66)
    ... 50 more
```

Entity role :

```
public class Roles implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idRoles;
    private String denomination;
    private boolean actif = true;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role")
    private Collection<PermissionsRoles> permissionsRoles;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Collection<Utilisateurs> utilisateurs;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "IdRoles", nullable = false)
    public int getIdRoles() {
        return idRoles;
    }

    public void setIdRoles(int idRoles) {
        this.idRoles = idRoles;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Denomination", nullable = false, length = 150)
    public String getDenomination() {
        return denomination;
    }

    public void setDenomination(String denomination) {
        this.denomination = denomination;
    }


    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Actif", nullable = false)
    public boolean isActif() {
        return actif;
    }

    public void setActif(boolean actif) {
        this.actif = actif;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Roles roles = (Roles) o;
        return idRoles == roles.idRoles &&
                actif == roles.actif &&
                Objects.equals(denomination, roles.denomination);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(idRoles, denomination, actif);
    }

    public Collection<PermissionsRoles> getPermissionsRoles() {
        return permissionsRoles;
    }

    public void setPermissionsRoles(Collection<PermissionsRoles> pr) {
        this.permissionsRoles = pr;
    }


    public Collection<Utilisateurs> getUtilisateurs() {
        return utilisateurs;
    }

    public void setUtilisateurs(Collection<Utilisateurs> user) {
        this.utilisateurs = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Roles clone(){
        Roles role = null;
        try{
            role = (Roles) super.clone();
        }catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
        return role;
    }

    public void setFields(Roles role) {
        this.denomination = role.denomination;
        this.actif = role.actif;
        this.permissionsRoles = role.permissionsRoles;
        this.utilisateurs = role.utilisateurs;
    }
```

My service :

```
public class SvcRoles extends Service<Roles> implements Serializable {
    // Déclaration des variables
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SvcRoles.class);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public SvcRoles() {
        super();
    }

    // Méthode qui permet de sauver un role et de le mettre en DB
    @Override
    public Roles save(Roles roles) {
        if (roles.getIdRoles() == 0) {
            em.persist(roles);
        } else {
            roles = em.merge(roles);
        }

        return roles;
    }
```

and my save()

```
public void save()
    {
        SvcRoles serviceR = new SvcRoles();
        SvcPermissions serviceP = new SvcPermissions();
        SvcPermissionRoles servicePR = new SvcPermissionRoles();
        servicePR.setEm(serviceR.getEm());
        EntityTransaction transaction = serviceR.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        try {
            serviceR.save(role);
            serviceR.refreshEntity(role);
            if(role.getPermissionsRoles().size()>0){
                for(PermissionsRoles pr : role.getPermissionsRoles())
                {
                    servicePR.delete(pr.getIdPermissionsRoles());
                }
            }
            for(Permissions p : listPerm)
            {
                if(serviceP.findOnePermission(p).size()>0){
                    servicePR.save(servicePR.createPermissionRoles(serviceP.findOnePermission(p).get(0),role));
                }
                else{
                    transaction.rollback();
                    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                    fc.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
                    fc.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"L'operation n'a pas reussie",null));
                    break;
                }
            }
            transaction.commit();
            FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            fc.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
            fc.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"L'operation a reussie",null));
        } finally {
            if (transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
                FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                fc.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
                fc.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"L'operation n'a pas reussie",null));
            }
            serviceR.close();
        }

    }
```

and my web page :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:f = "http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:shiro="http://shiro.apache.org/tags"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:composition template="Template/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">#{I18N['role.form.nouveau.titre']}</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
        <shiro:hasPermission name="Roles:Creer">
            <h:form id="form" prependId="false">
                <h:head>
                    <title>#{I18N['role.form.nouveau.titre']}</title>
                </h:head>
                <h2 style="text-align:center">#{I18N['role.form.nouveau.titre']}</h2>
                <p:panelGrid style="margin: 0 auto;" styleClass="ui-noborder" id="newrecform" columns="2" columnClasses="col1Newrec,col2Newrec,col3Newrec">

                    <p:outputLabel value = "#{I18N['role.label.Denomination']}" indicateRequired="true"/>
                    <p:inputText id="roleDenomination"
                                 validatorMessage="La valeur doit être entre 2 et 100 caracteres"
                                 value="#{rolesBean.role.denomination}"
                                 required="true"
                                 requiredMessage="#{I18N['formulaire.message.required.denomination']}"
                                 maxlength="100">
                        <f:validateLength minimum="2" maximum="100"/>
                        <p:tooltip for="roleDenomination" value="#{I18N['tooltip.role.deno']}" position="right"/>
                    </p:inputText>

                    <p:outputLabel value = "#{I18N['Permissions.label.Type']}" indicateRequired="true"/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu value = "#{permissionsBean.type}" id="type" >
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}"/>
                        <f:selectItems value = "#{permissionsBean.permissionsType}" var="ty"
                                       itemLabel="#{ty}"
                                       itemValue="#{ty}"/>
                        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{permissionsBean.getPermissionsAction}" update="form:action" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <p:outputLabel value = "#{I18N['Permissions.label.Action']}" indicateRequired="true"/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu value = "#{permissionsBean.action}" id="action">
                        <f:selectItems value = "#{permissionsBean.listAction}" var="ac"
                                       itemLabel="#{ac}"
                                       itemValue="#{ac}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:commandButton rendered="#{permissionsBean.action ne null}" icon="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle" value="#{I18N['permissions.label.add']}" action="#{rolesBean.addPermission}" ajax="false">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{rolesBean.pe.type}" value="#{permissionsBean.type}" />
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{rolesBean.pe.action}" value="#{permissionsBean.action}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:panelGrid>

                <p:dataTable value="#{rolesBean.listPerm}" emptyMessage="Aucun enregistrement trouvé" var="pe" id="tableListPerm"
                             Class="table" headerClass="table-header" rowClasses="table-odd-row,table-even-row">

                <p:column>
                    <!-- column header -->
                    <f:facet name="header">Type de permission</f:facet>
                    <!-- row record -->
                    <p:outputLabel value ="#{pe.type}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <!-- column header -->
                    <f:facet name="header">Action</f:facet>
                    <!-- row record -->
                    <p:outputLabel value ="#{pe.action}"/>
                </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <!-- column header -->
                        <f:facet name="header">Supprimer la permission</f:facet>
                        <!-- row record -->
                        <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle"  action="#{rolesBean.supPermission}" ajax="false">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{rolesBean.pe}" value="#{pe}" />
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>

                <p:commandButton style="float: right" icon="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle" value="#{I18N['application.button.validate']}" action="#{rolesBean.newRoles}" immediate="true"/>
                <p:commandButton style="float: left" icon="fa fa-fw fa-home" value="#{I18N['application.button.return']}" action="#{rolesBean.flushRol}" immediate="true"/>
            </h:form>
        </shiro:hasPermission>
        <shiro:lacksPermission name="Roles:Creer">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{I18N['application.page.accessrefuse']}"/>
        </shiro:lacksPermission>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>

</html>
```

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search on **Stackoverflow** about the [`javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326993/entitynotfoundexception-entity-no-longer-exists-in-the-database-on-em-refresh), you will find that the problem is in your `IdRoles` configuration. You defined it like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idRoles;

@Id  // should be removed
@Column(name = "IdRoles", nullable = false) // should be moved to field, int can't be null
public int getIdRoles() {
    return idRoles;
}
```

You can place `javax.persistence` annoutations on fields or on getters, but not on both.

See: [Hibernate Annoutations - Which is better, field or property access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594597/hibernate-annotations-which-is-better-field-or-property-access)

In your case, sometimes the persistence layer is reading properties from getter, and  it is missing the `@GeneratedValue()` annotation, so it is waiting for you to set an `id` for the entity, before saving it to the database.